# How to merge 2 dataframes with order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have 2 dataframes

**df_My** which looks like this

```
Seq    Grp
-----------
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      1
5      2
6      2
7      3
8      3
9      1
.
.
135    3
136    1
137    1
138    2
139    3
```

The other dataframe is df_Filer

**df_Filer**

```
Seq    Grp    Alg
-------------------
1      1      J
3      2      F
7      3      Z
136    1      M
137    1      R
138    2      T
139    3      Y
```

I want to merge both dataframes into 1 where

1- if df_My Seq number has is already in df_Filer then it should merge with that number is df_My based on Seq in both df_My and df_Filter

2- if df_My Seq number is not in df_Filer then it should join with the smallest Seq in the same Grp

so the end result should be as follow

```
Seq    Grp    Alg
------------------
1      1      J
2      1      J
3      2      F
4      1      J
5      2      F
6      2      F
7      3      Z
8      3      Z
9      1      J
.
.
135    3      Z
136    1      M
137    1      R
138    2      T
139    3      Y
```

I tried this but it does not give me the expected result

```
df_Out = df_My.merge(df_Filter, axis=1), on='Grp')
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Python doesn't have a dataframe object, so I assumed you're dealing with a pandas df and added a pandas tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@sammywemmy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985062/how-to-merge-2-dataframes-with-order/71985271?noredirect=1#comment127198827_71985271), you could use `merge_asof`:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Seq', by='Grp')
```

---

Another options is, you can `left-merge`, then use `groupby` + `idxmin` to create a mapping from Grp to Alg for the missing values, then fill:

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Seq', how='left', suffixes=('','_')).drop(columns=['Grp_'])
no_nan = df_merged.dropna()
mapping = df_merged['Grp'].map(no_nan.loc[no_nan.groupby('Grp')['Seq'].idxmin(), ['Grp','Alg']].set_index('Grp')['Alg'])
df_merged['Alg'] = df_merged['Alg'].fillna(mapping)
```

Output:

```
    Seq  Grp Alg
0     1    1   J
1     2    1   J
2     3    2   F
3     4    1   J
4     5    2   F
5     6    2   F
6     7    3   Z
7     8    3   Z
8     9    1   J
9   135    3   Z
10  136    1   M
11  137    1   R
12  138    2   T
13  139    3   Y
```

Comment: `pd.merge_asof` might be helpful here as well

Comment: @sammywemmy that’s a nice idea. I’ll take a crack at it later if you don’t do it yourself :-)

Comment: Thanks, but no change happens after the 2nd line of df_merged.fillna(df_merged...
not sure what went wrong

Comment: @enke not sure what i am doing wrong. it is still not working "Nan"s for many rows

Comment: @asmgx maybe there are Grp numbers with no corresponding Algs? It works on this sample, right?

Comment: @enke Thanks heaps, the first option worked.